# deep clone an object

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, underscore.js, lodash

Say I have an object which looks something like this -

```
data = 
    a: 1
    b: 2
    c:
        d: 3
        e: 4
        f:
            g: 4
            h:
                i: 9
```

I want to write a function which quite essentially clones this object deeply but replacing the numbers by their smallest multiple of 10.

```
a: 10
b: 20
c:
    d: 30
    e: 40
    f:
        g: 40
        h:
            i: 90
```

I want to use lodash or underscore to write the least amount of code. This is what I have done currently -

```
execute = (key) ->
#console.log typeof key, key
if typeof key is 'number'
    return key * 10

result = {}
_.forIn key, (value, name) ->
    result[name] = execute value
return result
```

Please suggest some thing which is elegant and clean.

**Update:**

After going through the lodash lib more I found a better way -

```
_.cloneDeep data,(value) -> value * 10 if typeof value is 'number'
```

Comment: I wanted a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

A pure coffee version of your `execute` is

```
foo = (data, out={})->
  if typeof data is 'number'
    return data*10
  for k of data
    out[k] = foo(data[k])
  return out
foo(data)
```

A recursive expression like that is a elegant as they come.  Your `_.deepClone` is more compact, because it lets lo-dash do the recursion, but I'd hardly call it more elegant or better.